# What does three quotes do at the begining of a Wolfram Chat-Notebook?

Tags: chatai

Mathematica has a [list of commands](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/introducing-chat-notebooks-integrating-llms-into-the-notebook-paradigm/) to start a chat cell in a notebook.
Notably, the single quote starts a chat, double quote starts a "side chat", but triple quote is not listed.

If I type the triple quote (''') at the beginning of a cell, I get this icon

[image: icon for chat]

and some sort of chat interface. What is it?

Comment: I am not familiar with a triple quote, is it from a non default keyboard layout?

Comment: It acts somehow similar to putting `=` at the beginning of a cell. i.e. triple quotes to ChatGPT is like `=` to wolframAlpha.

Comment: @JasonB. It's the single quote ' three times in a row.